# Build a Freestyle project using Jenkins Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, artifact-deployer

I am trying to build a code which doesn't have a pom.xml. Also i want to deploy the same to artifactory. Is there a way to build such a project using pipeline job. I can use freestyle job for building the above project. But I was hoping if there is some way to achieve the same in pipeline job. Also I require the groovy script details for artifactory deployment of such kind of project in pipeline job. But the basic question I have is this even feasible?

UPDATE:

We have a freestyle project job in whcih which we package our freestyle code into .tar and then deploy to artifactory using Generic Artifactory Configuration.

[image]

Now I am trying to achieve the same using a pipeline job. I get the point that we can use shell script inside Groovy and can build a tar package but how to deploy the tar package to Artifactory using Pipeline job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have only 1 file , you can use maven deploy option , and upload the file.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html